# Generalized additive models vs. functional data models

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, functional-data-analysis

I am not sure I understand the difference between [functional data analysis](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/%7Estaicu/FDAtutorial/index.html) (FDA) and [GAM](https://m-clark.github.io/generalized-additive-models/application.html#gam).
Or in short, I was reading about GAM and I found the following model which seems like an FDA model (there is a base function and its coefficients).

$$f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^q b_j(x) \gamma_j$$

Could you please help me understand what are the differences between the two methods?

**UPDATE**

From the discussions [here](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/346) and [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/scalar-on-function-regression-using-stan/3406) it seems that someone can run all flavours of functional data analysis using GAM (or in brms). Also, [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/0470013192.bsa239) and [this](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12290) one give a short description of FDA vs traditional methods.

But still, I don't understand how the FDA is different from GAM.

Comment: I see it is a philosophy. FDA sees a scatterplot as a data point. An additive model sees a scatterplot and fits a curve to it (ditto for a neural network).

Comment: Ok, nice way to think of. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: In terms of regression I think that the Wikipedia article on [*functional regression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_regression) is actually quite decent. [Müller](https://anson.ucdavis.edu/~mueller/)'s work is very much focused on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

By trying both methods for some time now I see that a main difference is that in FDA you actually get functional coefficients, meaning that your coefficients are depended on a particular moment of your continuum.
So your covariates may have linear effect but you still can get a wiggly function. In contrast, with GAM you may fit a wiggly spline but you miss from interpretability.

Comment: You describe what is called a functional concurrent model.